# ElasticSearch: How to filter an array of objects with multiple filters?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
  "id": 9,
  "resolutions": [
    {
      "divisionId": 8
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 123,
  "resolutions": [
    {
      "employeeId": 1,
      "divisionId": 5
    },
    {
      "divisionId": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

The index consists of `document` objects, and each `document` has an array `resolutions` with objects. A `resolution` can be given either to an employee, or a division. Employee will have both `divisionId` and `employeeId`, but division will only have `divisionId`. I need to filter for divisions only.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "nested": {
                              "path": "resolutions",
                              "query": {
                                "terms": {
                                  "resolutions.divisionId": [
                                    660
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must_not": [
                          {
                            "nested": {
                              "path": "resolutions",
                              "query": {
                                "exists": {
                                  "field": "resolutions.employeeId"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "minimum_should_match": 2,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            ],
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that this query checks all objects of the resolution array. So if only one division is added to the array, I get the result back, but if I also add an employee, then I do not get it back.

How to fix this to return the result if at least one division exists in the array, regardless of what the other objects are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query was quite complicated.

Below will answer ÿour query

> If at least one division exists in the array, regardless of what the other objects are?

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "resolutions",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "resolutions.employeeId"
              }
            }
          ],
          "filter": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "resolutions.divisionId"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can replace exists condition in filter with terms query if you want to filter on some values.

Use [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html) if you want to find matching nested documents.